# Does passing lambdas violate encapsulation when they use a private member variable?

Tags: c++, lambda, encapsulation, c++-concepts

I wrote a function to pass to a third party's class. A static function worked fine until the function needed access to a private member variable to do its work. I can do that using a lambda expression (given that it is converted to std::function either automatically or by casting).

Example:

```
void classA::doingThings()
{
...
    classB::needsHelpToDoAThing(
    [&](std::type foo) -> size_t { return myFunction(foo); }
    );
...
}

size_t class::myFunction(type foo){
...
type someVar = m_somePrivateMember ...(some work)
...
}
```

But I don't really understand what I'm doing. Now this other class is using private member variables from a different class. Doesn't this violate encapsulation? Is this a hack or am I missing/misunderstanding a concept?

Comment: You are, essentially, passing `classA` pointer (stashed away inside a lambda) to `classB::needsHelpToDoAThing`, which then turns around and calls a method of `classA` through that pointer. The method of a class can, of course, access any members of that class. You could as well make it explicit and have `needsHelpToDoAThing` take `classA*` as a parameter.

Comment: No, the "other" class is not using private member variables from "this" class. The other class is invoking a function pointer or a function object that's a member of "this" class, and, therefore, has full access to "this" class's private members and methods.

Comment: No encapsulation is broken. Everything is fine. As you were.

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down for me. Explaining it in terms of pointers makes it seem much more reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulation is the idea that other code doesn't get to poke around in your innards willy-nilly.

Here you created a helper function that can poke around in your innards.  This helper function is *part* of your innards, even if you pass it to someone else.

This no more breaks encapsulation than a member method accessing private data.  While it isn't part of the interface of the class explicitly, it is still part of the implementation.